# C++ cut out part of std::string and assign another one

Tags: c++, string, std

I want to get part of a std::string, assign that part to another empty std::string, and then remove that part from the original string. I wonder how to do it in one line?

Is there any string methods to do something like that ? ->

```
std::cout << oldStr; // "Hello world!";

std::string newStr = oldStr.someMethod("Hello");

std::cout << newStr; // "Hello"
std::cout << oldStr; // " world!"
```

Comment: Here's how I would approach this. Step 1: go to my favorite C++ reference site. Step 2: start reading through `std::basic_string`'s methods, one after another, looking for one that does that. Based on that, it's pretty easy to determine if there are "any string methods to do something like that". String methods are not some deeply-held secret, only known to a few elite C++ gurus. They're all publicly documented, on multiple reference sites.

Comment: Hmmm. [Let's take a look...](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Doesn't look like it, so [what about the algorithm library?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). Looks like plenty of two-step options, but no all-in-one solution.

Comment: Use SNOBOL. `oldStr pattern . newStr =`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the exact string you can use the substring method `substr`

```
std::string oldStr = "Hello world!";

std::cout << oldStr << std::endl; // "Hello world!"

std::string newStr = oldStr.substr(0, 5);
oldStr = oldStr.substr(6);
    
std::cout << newStr << std::endl; // "Hello"
std::cout << oldStr << std::endl; // " world!"
```

Comment: Note: you can ditch the `, 11`. By default `substr` reads to the end of the `string`.

Comment: Nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `’\n’` ends a line.

Comment: If the target substring is not at the front of the original string then you need to use `erase()` instead of `substr()` to remove it: `std::string newStr = oldStr.substr(index, length); oldStr.erase(index, length);`